# In iOS when must I run something on the main thread?

Tags: ios, thread-safety

I have a game that I'm getting ready to submit. I've tested it a lot and it seems to be solid -- no crashes and no unexpected behavior. I am not forcing anything to run on the main thread (except for one place where I followed a sample in a book) and now I'm concerned that under some circumstance, on somebody else's device, the game will not work right or crash because I'm not doing something on the main thread that should be on the main thread. But I don't understand what needs to be run on the main thread. I googled for a checklist or summary of what methods need run on the main thread and didn't find anything useful. Is this something I need to worry about? The app is for iOS 5.1 and up and it uses in-app purchases and Game Center. I use the cocos2d framework and also a lot of UIKit stuff.

Comment: The first question would be: When are you running something on a background thread?  If you don't run anything on a background thread everything will be run on the main thread.

Comment: Right after posting this question I found the question "When do I need to worry about thread-safety in an iOS application?" It has some good answers including a reference to the "Concurrency Programming Guide".

Comment: As a rule of thumb, any calls to UI library code should be on the main thread. In practice, most code is usually on the main thread unless it specifically needs to be in a background thread. Are you actually running anything in a background thread? If not, you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: I am using GameKit methods like loadAchievementsWithCompletionHandler: and the documentation for that says "Keep in mind that the completion handler may be called on a thread other than the one originally used to invoke the method. This means that the code in your block needs to be thread-safe." But now I'm not doing anything special to be "thread-safe" and nothing seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

most methods running on the main thread are fine, 
especially the UI,

you want to use the back thread for processes that can take long, like http requests, database or data sorting, or any other process that can pause the user experience while is processing.

if you load lots of objects you can produce a memory warning that can result in a crash,

so you can release non needed objects when you get a memory release.

good luck